# Upload image from android camera to web server

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-camera

```
package com.camerafileupload;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // LogCat tag
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();


    // Camera activity request codes
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE = 200;

    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

    private Uri fileUri; // file url to store image/video

    private Button btnCapturePicture, btnRecordVideo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Changing action bar background color
        // These two lines are not needed
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(getResources().getString(R.color.action_bar))));

        btnCapturePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapturePicture);
        btnRecordVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRecordVideo);

        /**
         * Capture image button click event
         */
        btnCapturePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // capture picture
                captureImage();
            }
        });

        /**
         * Record video button click event
         */
        btnRecordVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // record video
                recordVideo();
            }
        });

        // Checking camera availability
        if (!isDeviceSupportCamera()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Your device doesn't support camera",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // will close the app if the device does't have camera
            finish();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checking device has camera hardware or not
     * */
    private boolean isDeviceSupportCamera() {
        if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            // this device has a camera
            return true;
        } else {
            // no camera on this device
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Launching camera app to capture image
     */
    private void captureImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    /**
     * Launching camera app to record video
     */
    private void recordVideo() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);

        // set video quality
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file
                                                            // name

        // start the video capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    /**
     * Here we store the file url as it will be null after returning from camera
     * app
     */
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        // save file url in bundle as it will be null on screen orientation
        // changes
        outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // get the file url
        fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
    }



    /**
     * Receiving activity result method will be called after closing the camera
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // if the result is capturing Image
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                // successfully captured the image
                // launching upload activity
                launchUploadActivity(true);


            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            } else {
                // failed to capture image
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                // video successfully recorded
                // launching upload activity
                launchUploadActivity(false);

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

                // user cancelled recording
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled video recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            } else {
                // failed to record video
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to record video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void launchUploadActivity(boolean isImage){
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UploadActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("filePath", fileUri.getPath());
        i.putExtra("isImage", isImage);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    /**
     * ------------ Helper Methods ---------------------- 
     * */

    /**
     * Creating file uri to store image/video
     */
    public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /**
     * returning image / video
     */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

        // External sdcard location
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                Config.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Oops! Failed create "
                        + Config.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }
}
```

I get this code from android hive, I didn't know where the code to upload the image to server. I already build this code into .apk it working when taking photo and video to local storage but not to server.

and this is uploadactivity

```
     package com.camerafileupload;

    import com.camerafileupload.AndroidMultiPartEntity.ProgressListener;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
    import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.widget.VideoView;

    public class UploadActivity extends Activity {
        // LogCat tag
        private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

        private ProgressBar progressBar;
        private String filePath = null;
        private TextView txtPercentage;
        private ImageView imgPreview;
        private VideoView vidPreview;
        private Button btnUpload;
        long totalSize = 0;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);
            txtPercentage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPercentage);
            btnUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            imgPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);
            vidPreview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPreview);

            // Changing action bar background color
            getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                    new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(getResources().getString(
                            R.color.action_bar))));

            // Receiving the data from previous activity
            Intent i = getIntent();

            // image or video path that is captured in previous activity
            filePath = i.getStringExtra("filePath");

            // boolean flag to identify the media type, image or video
            boolean isImage = i.getBooleanExtra("isImage", true);

            if (filePath != null) {
                // Displaying the image or video on the screen
                previewMedia(isImage);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry, file path is missing!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // uploading the file to server
                    new UploadFileToServer().execute();
                }
            });

        }

        /**
         * Displaying captured image/video on the screen
         * */


        private void previewMedia(boolean isImage) {
            // Checking whether captured media is image or video
            if (isImage) {
                imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                vidPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                // bimatp factory
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                // down sizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
                // images
                options.inSampleSize = 8;

                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

                imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } else {
                imgPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                vidPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                vidPreview.setVideoPath(filePath);
                // start playing
                vidPreview.start();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Uploading the file to server
         * */


        private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // setting progress bar to zero
                progressBar.setProgress(0);
                super.onPreExecute();
            }



            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
                // Making progress bar visible
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                // updating progress bar value
                progressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);

                // updating percentage value
                txtPercentage.setText(String.valueOf(progress[0]) + "%");
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                return uploadFile();
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            private String uploadFile() {
                String responseString = null;

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Config.FILE_UPLOAD_URL);

                try {
                    AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                            new ProgressListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void transferred(long num) {
                                    publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                                }
                            });

                    File sourceFile = new File(filePath);

                    // Adding file data to http body
                    entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));

                    // Extra parameters if you want to pass to server
                    entity.addPart("website",
                            new StringBody("www.fintech-dev.com/cpeco"));
                    entity.addPart("email", new StringBody("i117dr4@gmail.com"));

                    totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
                    httppost.setEntity(entity);

                    // Making server call
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

                    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                    if (statusCode == 200) {
                        // Server response
                        responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
                    } else {
                        responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                                + statusCode;
                    }

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    responseString = e.toString();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    responseString = e.toString();
                }

                return responseString;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Response from server: " + result);

                // showing the server response in an alert dialog
                showAlert(result);

                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }

        }

        /**
         * Method to show alert dialog
         * */


        private void showAlert(String message) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(message).setTitle("Response from Servers")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // do nothing
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }

    }

and this is androidmultipartentity

package com.camerafileupload;

import java.io.FilterOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class AndroidMultiPartEntity extends MultipartEntity

{

    private final ProgressListener listener;

    public AndroidMultiPartEntity(final ProgressListener listener) {
        super();
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public AndroidMultiPartEntity(final HttpMultipartMode mode,
            final ProgressListener listener) {
        super(mode);
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public AndroidMultiPartEntity(HttpMultipartMode mode, final String boundary,
            final Charset charset, final ProgressListener listener) {
        super(mode, boundary, charset);
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream) throws IOException {
        super.writeTo(new CountingOutputStream(outstream, this.listener));
    }

    public static interface ProgressListener {
        void transferred(long num);
    }

    public static class CountingOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {

        private final ProgressListener listener;
        private long transferred;

        public CountingOutputStream(final OutputStream out,
                final ProgressListener listener) {
            super(out);
            this.listener = listener;
            this.transferred = 0;
        }

        public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            out.write(b, off, len);
            this.transferred += len;
            this.listener.transferred(this.transferred);
        }

        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            out.write(b);
            this.transferred++;
            this.listener.transferred(this.transferred);
        }
    }
}
```

This is config

```
package com.camerafileupload;

public class Config {
     public static final String FILE_UPLOAD_URL = "url.com/android_upload/file_upload.php";

        // Directory name to store captured images and videos
        public static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "android_upload";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataHolder.FILE_UPLOAD_URL containing the url to upload.

onclick write

```
new UploadFileToServer().execute();

private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // setting progress bar to zero
                pDialog.setProgress(0);
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
                // Making progress bar visible


                // updating progress bar value
                pDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);

                // updating percentage value
            //  txtPercentage.setText(String.valueOf(progress[0]) + "%");
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                return uploadFile();
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            private String uploadFile() {

                String responseString = null;


                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(DataHolder.FILE_UPLOAD_URL);

                try {
                    AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                            new ProgressListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void transferred(long num) {
                                    publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                                }
                            });

                    File sourceFile = new File(filePath);

                    // Adding file data to http body
                    entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));

                    // Extra parameters if you want to pass to server

                    entity.addPart("username", new StringBody("xyz"));

                    totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
                    httppost.setEntity(entity);

                    // Making server call
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

                    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                    if (statusCode == 200) {
                        // Server response
                        responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
                    } else {
                        responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                                + statusCode;
                    }

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    responseString = e.toString();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    responseString = e.toString();
                }

                return responseString;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Response from server: " + result);

                // showing the server response in an alert dialog
                showAlert(result);

                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }

        }

        /**
         * Method to show alert dialog
         * */
        private void showAlert(String message) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setMessage(message).setTitle("Response from Servers")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // do nothing
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
```